# Breeze throws Null reference exception when calling EntityAspect.validateProperty() method

Tags: breeze

I have the following entity property defined as the following metadata shows:

```
{"name":"website","dataType":"String",
    "validators":[
        {"name":"string"},
        {"messageTemplate":"'%displayName%' is not valid",
            "pattern":"^$|(^http|^https)://[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/S*)?",
            "name":"regExValidator"}]}
```

When I attempt to call `entityAspect.validateProperty("website")`, and the value of the `website` property is null, the call to the `validateProperty()` method throws the following exception:

> "Unable to get property 'complexAspect' of undefined or null
>   reference"

I wouldn't expect this behavior since it's possible that the `website` entity property could be null. It looks like there may be a null reference handling bug in the `validateProperty` method:

In **Breeze.debug.js**:

```
proto.validateProperty = function (property, context) {
    var value = this.getPropertyValue(property); // performs validations

    if (value.complexAspect) { // THROWS EXCEPTION IF 'value' IS NULL
        return validateTarget(value);
    }

    context = context || {};
    context.entity = this.entity;
    if (typeof(property) === 'string') {
        context.property = this.entity.entityType.getProperty(property, true);
        context.propertyName = property;
    } else {
        context.property = property;
        context.propertyName = property.name;
    }

    return this._validateProperty(value, context);
};
```

Just curious if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is just a bug?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This was fixed in Breeze v1.3.0, available now.

---

This is a bug, and will be fixed in the next release, out later this week.  ... and thx for finding and reporting it :)

Comment: Great, I'll look forward to the upcoming fix.